# Python Tweepy block user returns 401 Unauthorized

Tags: python, block, tweepy, http-status-code-401, unauthorized

I am trying to block a Twitter user using Python scripting and the Tweepy API. I am able to extract users, IDs, followers and tweets with no problem. When I try to call `api.create_block(screen_name = '<some person I don't like>')`
I get an exception
`401 Unauthorized`
(and that user is not blocked). I have been googling but only found old posts referring to my Windows time being not in sync. I synced the time and no improvement. I also tried blocking by ID but no luck.
Can anybody help ?

Comment: Can you show your authentication code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Make sure your app has the write permission.
>
> After giving it the write permission, make sure to regenerate and use new credentials to utilize it.

https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.8.0/faq.html#why-am-i-encountering-a-401-unauthorized-error-with-api-or-403-forbidden-error-with-client

Answer (score 0):

I am using OAuth 2.0 which does not allow separate read or write permissions. I tried with refreshed credentials but still the same.
I did enable OAuth 1.0a and regenerated credentials (again) and now I can block users, Thanks !

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).